# How avoid calling setApplicationContext on a SpringResourceTemplateResolver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, applicationcontext

I'm currently setting up a Spring MVC project with Thymeleaf, following the tutorial at: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#spring-mvc-configuration

Trying to KISS the code, I first replaced `implements ApplicationContextAware` and the setter method with `@Inject private ApplicationContext applicationContext`.
But I don't understand why I have to call `setApplicationContext()` on the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` while it inherits the Spring interface `ApplicationContextAware`.

How to avoid this?

Edit:
If I remove the `templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);` line, I get this exception when accessing the root:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application Context cannot be null
    org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.<init>(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:64)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(SpringResourceTemplateResolver.java:69)
    org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.java:1221)
    org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver.resolveTemplate(AbstractTemplateResolver.java:356)
    org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:840)
    org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:608)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Note: I use the latest versions: Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE and Thymeleaf 3.0.2.RELEASE (of course I imported `thymeleaf-spring4`).

Comment: This is only a suggestion and does not answer your question: You could try to use Spring Boot with http://start.spring.io/, which will generate you a ready to use and preconfigured project with Thymeleaf and Spring MVC.

Comment: You don't need to, nor don't you need to inject the context. Spring will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @kamwo , I'm aware of all the Spring Boot auto-generated projects. But I wanted to fully understand how the Spring Java config works, as I've almost always encountered XML-based configuration projects (legacy projects...). As well as organize the whole project & dependencies by my own.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried before, and I get an exception, see my edit.

Comment: Also make sure you removed the `ApplicationContextAware` and inject of the `ApplicationContext`. If that doesn't work it looks like there is an issue with the lifecycle inside Thymeleaf.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have effectively commented out the ``@Inject applicationContext`` (and my config class didn't implement ApplicationContextAware).

Comment: And that's what they explain in the migration guide to Thymeleaf 3: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html

Comment: And you are using the most recent versions of the libraries?

Comment: In the migration guide it is needed because the resolver isn't a `@Bean` if you followed the guide the bean should be a spring bean and will be injected. Post your configuration class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was about to post my config class, then found out that maybe the missing ``@Configuration`` annotation could the source of the problem. Bingo! That's it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-checking what I missed, it appears the missing `@Configuration` annotation is the source of Spring not injecting the `ApplicationContext` into the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`.